# How to show WebP images in Windows Phone 8 (Silverlight)

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

How do I show WebP images in Windows Phone 8's Image control where it only supports jpeg and png. I have found a decoder for GIFs but nothing for WebP. Help.

Answer (score 0):

I have a library for decoding WebP in Universal Windows Platform (Windows 10). If you're targeting WP10 you can just install the SDK but since you're using 8.0 you can try working with the source code:

https://github.com/zumicts/Universal.WebP

Go into properties of all the C++ projects and change the target platform to WP8.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try this.